# Spring Scheduler - How to know the Scheduler Status? [Active or Inactive]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I am using Spring boot 2.0.0. For Spring Scheduler, implementing the `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfigurer` in my start up class and I am starting the scheduler from UI through API service. Scheduler is running fine.

How do I know the currently running scheduler status? If I try to run the same scheduler again, how to configure any error or exception, so that we know it is already running?

Comment: Umm, you forgot your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is some built-in functionalities, but you can still set an AtomicBoolean when your scheduler start and stop and create webservices to get the values.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion, As suggested, I am going to use the AtomicBoolean implementation for now.

Comment: Note that if your have a lot of @Scheduler, you can still use Spring-Aop to generate the status for all the scheduler.